# Why does adding a WHERE clause make this untranslatable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The following works just fine:

```
myStatements = db.Statements.Select(s => new StatementModel
{
    StatmentId = s.StatementId,
    EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = s.Employee.FirstName,
    LastName = s.Employee.LastName,
    PlanVariantType = s.Employee.PlanVariantType != null ? s.Employee.PlanVariantType.PlanVariantTypeName : "",
    FiscalPeriod = s.FiscalPeriod != null ? s.FiscalPeriod.FiscalPeriodName : "",
    CostCenterId = s.Employee.CostCenterId,
    EVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.LastName : "",
    SVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.LastName : "",
    LOBMgrName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.LastName : "",
    AdminApprovalStatus = s.AdminApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatusName,
    StatementStatus = s.StatementStatus.StatementStatusName,
    AmountDue = s.AmountDue
}).ToList();
```

But if I add a simple `WHERE` clause it throws an exception saying it can't be translated:

```
myStatements = db.Statements.Select(s => new StatementModel
{
    StatmentId = s.StatementId,
    EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = s.Employee.FirstName,
    LastName = s.Employee.LastName,
    PlanVariantType = s.Employee.PlanVariantType != null ? s.Employee.PlanVariantType.PlanVariantTypeName : "",
    FiscalPeriod = s.FiscalPeriod != null ? s.FiscalPeriod.FiscalPeriodName : "",
    CostCenterId = s.Employee.CostCenterId,
    EVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.LastName : "",
    SVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.LastName : "",
    LOBMgrName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.LastName : "",
    AdminApprovalStatus = s.AdminApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatusName,
    StatementStatus = s.StatementStatus.StatementStatusName,
    AmountDue = s.AmountDue
}).Where(s => s.StatementStatusId == "PAA").ToList();
```

The exception message is a mess and isn't helpful beyond telling me that it couldn't be translated.

So what's the issue with the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: dotnetstep answer gives you the correct solution.  As to your question: by putting `.Where` *after* the `.Select`, you are applying the it on the `IEnumerable<StatementModel>` that is being returned by the `Select` method, rather than on your `DbSet`.  This is why you need to place it after your `DbSet` and  before the `Select` as per dotnetstep's answer.

Comment: @Superman.Lopez `Queryable.Select` also returns `IQueryable<>`, so that is *not* the reason. The real reason is that EF Core 3+ supports client evaluation of some untranslatable projection (`Select`) when it is the *final* query operator. The OP's `Select` contains untranslatable parts, thus only works if it is the last query operator. Adding any other (`Where`, `OrderBy` etc,, doesn't matter) after it will lead to the same runtime exception regardless of the fields used in the additional operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Use where clause first then projection.

```
myStatements = db.Statements.Where(s => s.StatementStatusId == "PAA").Select(s => new StatementModel
{
    StatmentId = s.StatementId,
    EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = s.Employee.FirstName,
    LastName = s.Employee.LastName,
    PlanVariantType = s.Employee.PlanVariantType != null ? s.Employee.PlanVariantType.PlanVariantTypeName : "",
    FiscalPeriod = s.FiscalPeriod != null ? s.FiscalPeriod.FiscalPeriodName : "",
    CostCenterId = s.Employee.CostCenterId,
    EVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.LastName : "",
    SVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.LastName : "",
    LOBMgrName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.LastName : "",
    AdminApprovalStatus = s.AdminApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatusName,
    StatementStatus = s.StatementStatus.StatementStatusName,
    AmountDue = s.AmountDue
}).ToList();
```

Comment: *"Use where clause first then projection"* Because...?

Comment: @IvanStoev I will provide much detail for this in answer. As of now I can say that when it projected first and then where clause so it execute on Model that part of select and which is not similar to Entity of DbContext so it will not find anything to map that field. If project first and then where clause then Select.AsEnumrable.Where should be chain. Here AsEnumrable make evaluation on client side which is executed on object instead query transform to SQL and then execute.

Answer (score 2):

Problem here that you have custom projection. It means that LINQ translator knows only fields which are explicitly mapped. `StatementStatusId` has no mapping and Translator throws error. Add mapping and query will work:

```cs
myStatements = db.Statements.Select(s => new StatementModel
{
    StatmentId = s.StatementId,
    EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = s.Employee.FirstName,
    LastName = s.Employee.LastName,
    PlanVariantType = s.Employee.PlanVariantType != null ? s.Employee.PlanVariantType.PlanVariantTypeName : "",
    FiscalPeriod = s.FiscalPeriod != null ? s.FiscalPeriod.FiscalPeriodName : "",
    CostCenterId = s.Employee.CostCenterId,
    EVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Evp.LastName : "",
    SVPName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Svp.LastName : "",
    LOBMgrName = s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr != null ? s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.FirstName + " " + s.Employee.CostCenter.Lobmgr.LastName : "",
    AdminApprovalStatus = s.AdminApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatusName,
    StatementStatus = s.StatementStatus.StatementStatusName,
    AmountDue = s.AmountDue,
    // missing mapping
    StatementStatusId = s.StatementStatusId
}).Where(s => s.StatementStatusId == "PAA").ToList();
```

Comment: This would have the same issue of EF not knowing how to translate a where clause on a non-entity into SQL.